# are there any other ways to refactor/reuse structs when it comes to unmarshaling and resolving dynamic types?

Tags: go

I'm expecting JSON payload with some fields of ambiguous types. To be exact I need to either process single object or slice of objects.

Example of a single object:

```
{
    "service": {
        "serviceName": "serviceName",
        "serviceAttribute": {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Example of slice of objects:

```
{
    "service": [
        {
            "serviceName":"serviceName",
            "serviceAttribute": [
                {
                    "name":"name",
                    "value":"value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see here field **service** and **serviceAttribute** may be a single object enclosed in curly brackets or a collection of objects enclosed within square brackets and curly brackets.

The data model I am expected to return is exactly as second example:

```
{
    "service": [
        {
            "serviceName":"serviceName",
            "serviceAttribute": [
                {
                    "name":"name",
                    "value":"value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to kind of sanitize ambiguous JSON payloads into an object with concrete types for easy processing further in the code, without any need of resolving types anywhere in the code.
I would like for all of the resolving to be done once at the beginning so I would not need to bother later with resolving types like **json.RawMessage** each time I need to use them.

My real life case involves much more complex data structure deeply nested. I would like to keep my current structs as concise as possible with as least repetitions as possible. As you may see in the example provided below I am copying 2 structs and I just wonder if that is the most clean way of handling that.

I've prepared a code that works as intended and fulfills the requirements I've stated above.
[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ab9_tNW2vMH)
Could someone guide me on what could be improved here or point me what I may be doing wrong?
Is undertaken approach a generally proper way of solving my case?

All help will be appreciated, thanks.

I've tried look for solutions via chat with ChatGPT and browse through web for similar use cases and it seems like there are plenty of resources regarding solely handling dynamic types but not necessarily fitting wider in the context of my exact use case.

Full code attached as well here.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type InType struct {
    Service json.RawMessage `json:"service,omitempty"`
}

type Service struct {
    ServiceName      string          `json:"serviceName,omitempty"`
    ServiceAttribute json.RawMessage `json:"serviceAttribute,omitempty"`
}

type ServiceAttribute struct {
    Name  string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Value string `json:"value,omitempty"`
}

type OutType struct {
    Service []*OutService `json:"service,omitempty"`
}

type OutService struct {
    ServiceName      string              `json:"serviceName,omitempty"`
    ServiceAttribute []*ServiceAttribute `json:"serviceAttribute,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    jsonDataSingle := `
    {
        "service": {
            "serviceName": "serviceName",
            "serviceAttribute": {
                "name": "name",
                "value": "value"
            }
        }
    }
    `

    jsonDataCollection := `
    {
        "service": [
            {
                "serviceName":"serviceName",
                "serviceAttribute": [
                    {
                        "name":"name",
                        "value":"value"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    `
    fmt.Println("processing single")
    err := UnmarshalAndResolve([]byte(jsonDataSingle))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("----------------------")

    fmt.Println("processing collection")
    err = UnmarshalAndResolve([]byte(jsonDataCollection))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func UnmarshalAndResolve(data []byte) error {
    // loading part
    var in *InType

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &in)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // resolving part
    service := resolveServiceType(in.Service)

    outServices := []*OutService{}
    for _, s := range service {

        serviceAttributes := resolveServiceAttributeType(s.ServiceAttribute)

        os := &OutService{
            ServiceName:      s.ServiceName,
            ServiceAttribute: serviceAttributes,
        }

        outServices = append(outServices, os)
    }

    // creating object with concrete types so i wont need anymore resolving steps further in the code
    out := &OutType{
        Service: outServices,
    }

    for _, s := range out.Service {
        fmt.Println(s.ServiceName)
        for _, sa := range s.ServiceAttribute {
            fmt.Println(sa.Name)
            fmt.Println(sa.Value)

        }
    }

    return nil
}

func resolveServiceType(service json.RawMessage) []*Service {
    fmt.Println("resolveServiceType")
    var single *Service
    var collection []*Service

    switch {
    case json.Unmarshal(service, &single) == nil:
        fmt.Println("single")
        return []*Service{single}
    case json.Unmarshal(service, &collection) == nil:
        fmt.Println("collection")
        return collection
    default:
        return []*Service{}
    }
}

func resolveServiceAttributeType(serviceAttribute json.RawMessage) []*ServiceAttribute {
    fmt.Println("resolveServiceAttributeType")
    var single *ServiceAttribute
    var collection []*ServiceAttribute

    switch {
    case json.Unmarshal(serviceAttribute, &single) == nil:
        fmt.Println("single")
        return []*ServiceAttribute{single}
    case json.Unmarshal(serviceAttribute, &collection) == nil:
        fmt.Println("collection")
        return collection
    default:
        fmt.Println("default")
        return []*ServiceAttribute{}
    }
}
```

Comment: The people who decided to replace a one entry list with a non-list of that item should be forced to answer this question.  That is a really stupid decision that doesn't make their lives easier but makes your life suck.  Tell them they're wrong.

Comment: Please include any relevant code **in the question**. If the remote link to your code expires, this question becomes much less useful to future readers.

Comment: I think that the solution below should meet your needs, but also agree with @erik258 that this is a poor implementation that just makes things confusing.  The more that you handle poorly formatted input, the more likely that bad input will get accepted.

Comment: @erik258 Yeah, I am aware of that, and I'm pretty sure the authors of that service which produces such JSONs are aware too. Sadly I can't do anythig about it. I've gotta work with what I've got.

Answer (score 5):

Declare a generic slice type that handles arrays or single values:

```
type ArrayOrObject[T any] []T

func (ao *ArrayOrObject[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {

    // It's an array if the data starts with [.
    if bytes.HasPrefix(data, []byte("[")) {
        // Prevent recursion by declaring type with no methods.
        type ArrayOrObjectNoMethods ArrayOrObject[T]
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*ArrayOrObjectNoMethods)(ao))
    }

    // Otherwise, assume a single value (object, string, ...). 
    // Create the slice and unmarshal to the first slice element.
    *ao = make([]T, 1)
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &(*ao)[0])
}
```

Use it like this:

```
type Service struct {
    ServiceName      string
    ServiceAttribute []Attribute
}

type Attribute struct {
    Name  string
    Value string
}

type Payload struct {
    Example string
    Service ArrayOrObject[Service] // <-- Yucky!
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Kk4KuFpWD80

The slice type adds clutter to the application types. We will move that clutter to an UnmarshalJSON method on the Payload type.  First, declare Payload as it should be:

```
type Payload struct {
    Example string
    Service []Service
}
```

Here's the UnmarshalJSON method:

```
func (p *Payload) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Prevent recursion by declaring type with same fields
    // as payload, but none of the methods.
    type PayloadNoMethods Payload

    // Declare and initialize a target for Unmarshal.
    var x = struct {
        *PayloadNoMethods
        // Shadow the Service field.
        Service *ArrayOrObject[Service]
    }{
        // All fields point back to the receiver. This eliminates
        // copying after the call to unmarshal.            
        (*PayloadNoMethods)(p),
        (*ArrayOrObject[Service])(&p.Service),
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &x)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/d25JwwaSWHw